# .NET Entity framework generates query with Table.ModelName_Column convention

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, sqlite

i've started working with ASP.NET MVC and using Entity Framework, concretely with SQLite db,
but i've got a little problem:

I've got a one to many relation, but EF generates wrong query,

```
SQLite error
no such column: Extent1.Category_CategoryID
```

so, he uses ModelName as a prefix and it's wrong.
Is there any convention, which i can remove? Or set off?

thx and sorry for my bad english

// Update, added Category entity

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace Eshop.Domain.Entities
{
    [Table("Categories")]
    public class Category
    {
        public Int64 CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

// added Product entity

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Eshop.Domain.Entities
{
    [Table("Products")]
    public class Product
    {
        public Int64 ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the entity class?

Comment: And what is the LINQ query you are running? Is `Extent1` the `Categories` table? Somehow `Category_CategoryID` looks more like a foreign key from another table...

Comment: The query is autogenerated by EF, Extent1 should be Categories. CategoryID contain both entity, Product and Category, in category case it's primary key and in product only single column. So, it's one to many relation, Categories.CategoryID => Products.CategoryID.

Comment: Can you also show the `Product` class?

Comment: I came across this error. Could you please post me the correct way ( I mean with back referencing in both class) please @Ramses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Code-First (which I assume) you need to...

- either introduce a navigation property in `Product`:

  ```
  [Table("Products")]
  public class Product
  {
      public Int64 ProductID { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public decimal Price { get; set; }
      public int CategoryID { get; set; }

      public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  EF will recognize `CategoryID` as foreign key then.
- or configure `CategoryID` as foreign key with Fluent API:

  ```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
      .HasMany(c => c.Products)
      .WithRequired()
      .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryID);
  ```

Comment: Ooou, i've forgot the back reference property(mean Category). And there was also problem with EF, he couldn't recognize the foreign key(using SQLite, maybe wrong table structure). Little fix needed in public Int64 CategoryID { get; set; } // EF needed. Thx a lot for help.